# Replacing string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I've got a string with various hex values in random places.

Is it possible to replace all hex values to a single value `#FF0000` ?

```
var info_str = 'The avocado, also known as butter pear or alligator pear, is a fruit that is widely "acknowledged to #E5E5E5 have properties" that reduce cholesterol levels... also #00FF00 ...';
```

I need to replace all hex values `#xxxxxx` with `#FF0000`. How can I do that?

`replace()` does not work because the hex values in the string are different.

Comment: where is the text written into span or p or div? can you specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex as `/#[\da-f]{6}/` , also add flags `ig` for ignoring case and global match

```js
var info_str = 'The avocado, also known as butter pear or alligator pear, is a fruit that is widely "acknowledged to #FFF001 have properties" that reduce cholesterol levels... also #00FF00 ...';
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = info_str.replace(/#[\da-f]{6}/ig, '#FF0000');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**Explanation :**

```
#[\da-f]{6}
```

1. `#` matches the character #
2. `\d` for matching any digit
3. `a-f` for matching letters a,b,c,d,e or f, since hex value contains only these alphabets
4. `{6}` Exactly 6 times

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PD-OeKfKXtcXtAM4)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY1aG2/1)

Comment: Why `da-f` ? and not `da-z` ?

Comment: @Becky it's `\d` Matches any digit and `a-z` matches any alphabet from `a` to `z`. As the hex are from `a` - `f`, there's no need of using `a-z`

Comment: @Becky The alphabets after `f` are not valid HexaDecimal Characters. Only `a` to `f` are valid for Hex value

Comment: How can I write the full updated string in to a div? `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText = info_str;` ?

Comment: `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = info_str`

Comment: `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = info_str.replace(/#[\da-f]{6}/ig,'#FF0000')`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple regex like

```js
var info_str = 'The avocado, also known as butter pear or alligator pear, is a fruit that is widely "acknowledged to #E5E5E5 had (property" that reduce cholesterol levels... also #00FF00 ...';

var str = info_str.replace(/#[\da-z]+/ig, '#FF0000');

snippet.log(str)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: As per Pranav C Balan's answer, what's the difference between `#[\da-z]+` and `#[\da-f]{6}` ?

Comment: @Becky the one will check 6 digits, and the other will not have a limit on the numbers ie. #1234567899 will be matched.

Comment: @Becky that will make sure there is 6 hexa characters following `#`... mine just checks whether 1 or more characters is there

Comment: @MrNeo `g` for global match and `i` for caseinsensitive match. You can check my answer for more description http://stackoverflow.com/a/32370230/2025923

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regex` to replace all the hex values from the string.

```js
var info_str = 'The avocado, also known as butter pear or alligator pear, is a fruit that is widely "acknowledged to #E5E5E5 have properties" that reduce cholesterol levels... also #00FF00 ...';

var replaced = info_str.replace(/#[a-f0-9]{6}/gi, '#FF0000');

document.write(replaced);
```

**Regex Explanation**

1. `#`: Matches `#` literal
2. `[a-f0-9]`: Matches any of the range from `a` to `f` and `0` to `9`
3. `{6}`: Matches previous character class `6` times
4. `gi`: Global and incasesensitive match.

**Regex Visualization**

[image: Regex Visualization]

Answer (score 2):

Yes using this regex `/#[A-F0-9]{6}/gi` with `replace()` function:

```js
var info_str = 'The avocado, also known as butter pear or alligator pear, is a fruit that is widely "acknowledged to #E5E5E5 have properties" that reduce cholesterol levels... also #00FF00 ...';

var replaced = info_str.replace(/#[A-F0-9]{6}/gi, "#FF0000");

document.write("<b>"+replaced+"</b>");
```

This will match any Hex value and replace it.

**Explanation:**

- `#` matches the character `#` literally.
- `A-F` a single character in the range between A and F.
- `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9.
- *Quantifier:* `{6}` Exactly 6 times.
- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match).

Comment: WHat's the difference between the regex of yours and Balan's answer?

Comment: @Becky They are similar, he used `\d` for numbers and I used `0-9`, but they will lead to the same result, and we use `A-F` here because Hexadecimals can contain only A, B, C, D, E or F.

Comment: Great, and the `{6}` is telling that the hexadecimal will have exactly 6 chracters after `#`.